# Designing topology in storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am working in web analytics. I am going to use kafka, [storm](http://storm-project.net/) and mongodb. Kafka gives source to storm, Storm process the data and stores the data in mongodb.

**Requirement**

1. Storm receives one string which is in [elf](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html) format.
2. Filters the data(some filters to remove undefined data).
3. Have to  convert elf string to DBObject
4. save the DBobject in mongoDB.

For the above requirement how to create a topology(How many bolts can be used).

whether performance is directly proportional to no of bolts?

Whether i can go for `transactional` topology or `trident` topology?

Any help or suggestion will be greatful.

Comment: Using a `TopologyBuilder`? Have you read [the Storm tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial) about defining Spouts and Bolts, and then connecting them?

Comment: @ChrisMantle First of all thanks. Edited my question for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to follow the philosophy of Unix when designing bolt: "Do one thing and do it well".

- Bolt 'A' that filters the data.
- Bolt 'B' to convert the out put of bolt 'A' to DBObject and save it to MongoDB.

This way you are keeping your topology simple. Simple and focused responsibility for each bolt. If something failed, you know exactly what could the problem. And of course, you can tell Storm how many parallelization is needed for each bolt.

I don' think you need any special abstractions (trident or transactional). The regular Storm topology serves you well here.

Any by the way, Storm documentation is excellent!

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Spout ---> bolt1 ----> bolt2 ----> mongodb. I am having one doubt bolt2 is depends on bolt1 so it will wait for bolt1 everytime even bolt2 doesn't have any task.

Comment: It is not a problem. Consider that you are going to implement this in Akka actors system. It is not a requirement that every actor should do something at any given point in the timeline. Same is true for Storm.

Comment: Even in threads, threads waits for others to finish their jobs.

Comment: I have read about this in https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Transactional-topologies#design-2

Comment: Exactly, what I mean is https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Transactional-topologies#design-3-storms-design